# Increase Autoincrement in Existing SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, auto-increment

I inherited a system that has a few flaws. Due to an oversight in the design of the system, we  are going to run into issues with future records. It will eventually cause a conflict with another table.

This table's primary key autoincements by 1 each time a new record is imported.  Currently there are about 50 records in the table.  I would like to be able to have the next new record's primary key equal to 60,000. After that the next record would be 60001, 60002, etc...

Can I safely modify this table so that the "Identity Increment" is 59950, then insert a record, then modify the table again and set the "Identity Increment" back to 1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at DBCC CHECKIDENT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Untested, but something like `DBCC CHECKIDENT ("MyTable", RESEED, 60000)`

Answer (score 1):

If ordering or values matter on a surrogate id, you've likely assigned business value to it. I'd reconsider what you are asking as this is likely the first of many problems for your design!